# Sahi recorder not recording website

Tags: sahi

I am using Sahi to automate some of my test cases. Sahi is recording lot of websites except my test website. It's not recording anything on my website.. Any suggestions or work around?

Answer (score 0):

I think an url to your site can be nice because the problem can be a lot of things.

For exemple, if you use flex instead of HTML, you should compile your flex application with Sahi's swc file. A flex application needs to be compiled with Sahi's swc file if your want to use Sahi on it.

All informations here :
https://sahipro.com/docs/using-sahi/flex.html#Introduction